# javascript getting width of browser and width of element

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I am not a coder but I need to center a fixed `<nav>`.

I tried adding `left:auto` `right:aut`o in my css it didnt work. So basically I wanted to do it in javascript and take the width of screen minus the width of the `<nav>` divide by 2 and set what left or right is.

But my javascript is bad and I basically don't know what I am doing. So if someone could help me out in the javascript or might have a fix without javascript.

HTML

```
<nav class="row container double pad-right pad-left">
 <ul class="pull-left">
  <a href="./">Home</a>
  <a>Main Menu</a>
  <a>Forums</a>
  <a href="./video">Video</a>
 </ul>
 <ul class="pull-right">
  <a>Sign in</a>
  <a>Register</a>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS that is added through javascript when screen reaches a certain height.

```
.nav-fixed{
  position:fixed !important;
  top:0 !important;
  float:none !important; 
  width:100%;
  background-color:#161616;
  height:33px;
  z-index:9000;
}
```

Javascript adding .nav-fixed

```
    $('document').ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 112) {

            $('nav').addClass('nav-fixed');

            }else{
            $('nav').removeClass('nav-fixed');
        }
    })});
```

Javascript of the screenwidth - elementwidth

```
$('document').ready(function() {
  $(window).width(function() {
    var window_width = $(window).width();
    var curr_width = $('nav').width();
    var center = (window_width-curr_width)/2
    if (window_width > cur_width){
      $('nav').css('right', $center, 'left', $center );
    }else if(window_width <= curr_width){
      $('nav').css('right', '0px', 'left', '0px');
 };
```

images of what is happening currently
https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1Mjb.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYzh3.jpg

FIX from HADI:

```
    function fix_top_bar(){
        var barWidth = $('.nav-fixed').width();
        $('.nav-fixed').css({ 'left' : '50%', 'margin-left' : '-' + (barWidth/2 + 20) + 'px' });
    }

    $('document').ready(function() {
            $(window).scroll(function() {
                if ($('body').scrollTop() > 112) {

                    $('nav').addClass('nav-fixed');
                    fix_top_bar();                              
                    }else{
                    $('.nav-fixed').css({ 'left' : '', 'margin-left' : ''});
                    $('nav').removeClass('nav-fixed');
                }
            });

        fix_top_bar();
        $(window).resize(function(){
              fix_top_bar();  
        });
        });
```

Comment: Your css will not target anything in the html snippet you have posted. There is nothing with a class of nav-fixed.

Comment: @ian yes i mentioned i made a javascript that adds it and its working. i didnt add it in there because I didnt want to make the post longer.

Comment: 100% width - that should negate any requirement for centring. Fixed relates to the viewport NOT the parent element. perhaps you could provide a link to what you are trying to achive (images or an online example).

Comment: just edited in the two pictures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please use -

```
$(window).width();
```

instead of `$(window).width(function());`

#### Update

see this - http://jsfiddle.net/ngGzX/3/

Comment: i fixed that but i still have an issue. plus i updated the top code.

Comment: can you fiddle your code? i can see that your css/js is not targeting anything!

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by fiddle your code. can you elaborate please?

Comment: go to http://jsfiddle.net/ and try to put your code which will run or show me what exactly you want. You can use paint or anything

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ngGzX/ ok I did it but the previous script i had isnt working on fiddle. basicly when you scroll down the navigation menu should snap into a fixed one.

Comment: just uploaded images in the top. it should show you my current issue

Comment: OK. See this image http://i.imgur.com/DXAl3mS.png i am seeing top black bar on left. You need it in center?

Comment: yes that is my issue. i have a script that when i scroll down it it adds the nav-fixed class. which is the black bar. but i cannot center it. i tried different stuff in the css and its not working so i was going to switch to javascript and code using the golden ratio.

Comment: You problem is solved here - http://jsfiddle.net/im4aLL/ngGzX/1/ take a look at this.

Comment: only issue with your code is when its <112 the home main video disapear. but the centering thing is working though

Comment: i noticed it disappears when i scroll down then back up again.

Comment: ok I just fixed it. You just needed to reset to the style once you removed in else. $('.nav-fixed').css({ 'left' : '', 'margin-left' : ''});

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort!! you helped me fix the problem =D.

Comment: this code seems to not work on firefox nor internet explorer. Do you know the reason?

Comment: code now works for firefox, didn't tested with IE. Hope it will work there also. see this jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ngGzX/3/ ~just change $('body').scrollTop() to $(window).scrollTop() and $('document') to $(document)

Answer (score 1):

You can perfectly well center content in CSS these days, without client side scripting.

If you merely want to center content inside a larger container horizonatally, you can simply apply the following rule to the content element:

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

Note that the above will set top and bottom margins to zero, but the most important effect is of course that it makes the browser calculate left and right margins as equal and divide the available margin space between the two, in effect centering the element (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#blockwidth).

If you want to center content vertically as well, you can use CSS table rendering capabilities:

```
<div style="display: table">
    <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle">
        <div style="margin: 0 auto">Nunc mollis volutpat tincidunt. Nunc ultrices feugiat ipsum, vulputate pellentesque urna pharetra at. Duis auctor, mauris a molestie blandit, felis enim tempus mauris, nec elementum dolor felis vel purus. Morbi vel tellus et velit tempus semper in eget nunc. Integer quis lacus justo. Pellentesque adipiscing, elit id lobortis ultricies, ante diam vulputate arcu, a egestas mauris diam quis metus. Maecenas iaculis urna a nulla iaculis a faucibus eros imperdiet. Maecenas ipsum libero, placerat a consectetur sit amet, mattis vel nisi. Donec laoreet porttitor pulvinar.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The above is a suggestion - I stripped it down to the required minimum for it to work. If you merely paste it in an empty document, you may not see the desired effect because you need to set up width and height of the container (an HTML page is by default `height: auto` which means it is as small as to fit its content) and perhaps also the width and/or height of the innermost element.

The outer element - the one that has `display: table` - doesn't have to be a `div` - it can be the `body` element for instance. You need to have `display: table` on an outer element, because otherwise `display: table-cell` in descendant elements does not work. The `display: table-cell` rule allows for `vertical-align: middle` to have the intended effect here - position the innermost element (the one with `margin: auto`) vertically in the middle. Finally, `margin: auto` has the same effect as before - the innermost element is positioned horizontally in the middle as well.

Depending on your layout, you might need to specify widths and/or heights to your liking, but the above is a functioning and very flexible template that works for elements of known and unknown sizes, as part of so-called "dynamic" or "floating" layout.

Comment: I think you meant `class="margin: 0 auto"` not `id="margin: 0 auto"`?

Comment: I have used margin:0 auto; for everything but for position: fixed; it is not working for some reason. I do not need vertical centering just horizontal. Do you know why margin: 0 auto is not working in my case?

Comment: @madmanali93 That makes little sense - if you fix elements position, you can't expect it to be in the middle of anything, you basically take it out of the rendered context! Which is why I want to ask you - what are you trying to accomplish? You want to center what? The navigation menu? Some of its elements? All of its elements within the menu? Also, you don't *need* to use `margin: 0 auto` for everything, or at least I'm not sure why you would do that?

Comment: I want to center the whole navigation menu when i scroll down. use this website for example http://arstechnica.com/ when you scroll down the navigation bar gets fixed in the center. I want to replicate the menu that they have. I have tried left: auto; right:auto; didn't center it. but when i do left: 10%; it moves it to that set location. so what i was thinking is making a javascript taking the screen width - the <nav> width divide by 2 and use that for left and right. I hope this makes more sense.

Comment: Here is what I wrote to look and work like on arstechnica.com:
http://jsfiddle.net/sr4u2/ The code looks larger than it really is due to decorations of sorts, your mileage may vary.

Comment: Thank you for your effort I appreciate it! =D