# Works for google chrome but not for firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

does anyone know why this works on chrome only. it is basically a code that snaps the nav-bar into the top when you scroll down by the nav-fixed class. and the function fix_top_bar is a way to center the bar that is created.

```
function fix_top_bar(){
    var barWidth = $('.nav-fixed').width();
    $('.nav-fixed').css({ 'left' : '50%', 'margin-left' : '-' + (barWidth/2 + 20) + 'px' });
}

$('document').ready(function() {
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($('body').scrollTop() > 112) {

                $('nav').addClass('nav-fixed');
                fix_top_bar();                              
                }else{
                $('.nav-fixed').css({ 'left' : '', 'margin-left' : ''});
                $('nav').removeClass('nav-fixed');
            }
        });

    fix_top_bar();
    $(window).resize(function(){
          fix_top_bar();  
    });
    });
```

Comment: Why do you need js to do this?

Comment: and what actually is happening in FF?

Comment: @gabe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16789256/javascript-getting-width-of-browser-and-width-of-element thats a whole other thread i had if you really want to check it out.

Comment: @AxelAmthor the javascript doesnt work. and javascript is enabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if ($('html').scrollTop() > 112) {`

instead of `$('body').scrollTop()` works for me in Firefox.

**Edit**

But that doesn't work in Chrome... doh.

**Another edit**

Ugly, but this works in both:

```
var scrollTop = Math.max($('body').scrollTop(), $('html').scrollTop());
if (scrollTop > 112) {
```

There's gotta be a better cross-browser solution...

Comment: ok so html works for firefox and body works for html but those two lines you gave dont seem to be working on both.

Comment: Here's the fiddle that appears to work for me in both FF and Chrome http://jsfiddle.net/qHN2x/

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is

```
$('document').ready(function() {
```

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() { // Note there is no tag <document>
```

Comment: didnt fix it. any thoughts?

Comment: @madmanali93 can you show CSS in your code.. also a working demo of your problem on jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com  will be helpful too..

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum No Idea

Comment: @rahulmaindargi http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16789256/javascript-getting-width-of-browser-and-width-of-element everything is in here and this is the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tQ46d/1/

Comment: @rahulmaindargi for some reason the one i sent you the script isnt working. http://jsfiddle.net/ngGzX/2/ this is though